# How to to create groups of php arrays encoded as json and return each group by name

Tags: php, json

is this possible? i want to return name and type of a car, in one json element.

The normal way is this,

```
{
    $return = array ('label' => $row['name'],
    'Type' => $row['Type'],

    );
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

But i want something like this so i can just call "NameType",

```
$return = array ('NameType' => $row['Name', 'Type'],
    );
```

the above should normally be like this.

I know my syntax is wrong.

Comment: `$return = array ('NameType' => array($row['Name'], $row['Type']));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understood well the question, but you can do

```
$return = array ('NameType' => $row['Name']." ".$row['Type']);
```

or

```
$return = array ('NameType' => array($row['Name'], $row['Type']));
```

Don't know exactly what you want to do

Comment: yes the first one is correct, Just that it returns the values without space in between.

Comment: Then just $row['Name']." ".$row['Type'] to add space between the two. I edited my answer to fit your comment